# CSV variable content to JSON variable content with Python

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm new to Python and I am trying to convert a variable which contains CSV data in JSON format. I tried this but, as you see, the result is not the expected one:

```
>>> data = "a1;b1;c1\na2;b2;c2\na3;b3;c3"
>>>
>>> print data
a1;b1;c1
a2;b2;c2
a3;b3;c3
>>>
>>> fieldnames = ["col1","col2","col3"]
>>>
>>> csv_reader = csv.DictReader(data,fieldnames)
>>>
>>> json.dumps([r for r in csv_reader])
[{"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": "a"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": "1"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": ";"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": "b"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": "1"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": ";"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": "c"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": "1"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": "a"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": "2"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": ";"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": "b"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": "2"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": ";"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": "c"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": "2"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": "a"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": "3"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": ";"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": "b"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": "3"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": ";"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": "c"}, {"col2": null, "col3": null, "col1": "3"}]'
```

What can I do to make my simple program read the variable line to line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues here.

First, `csv.DictReader` does not operate on string. Instead, you should pass an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator).

You have two options here:

- Convert your string to a file-like object (one that implements methods such as `.read`, etc.).
- Convert your string to a list (which is an iterator). You can do that using `.splitlines()`. Credit for this suggestion goes to Martijn Pieters down in the comments.

You can turn a string into a file-like object using the `StringIO.StringIO` class (note that in Python 3, this is `io.StringIO`):

```
import StringIO
import csv

data = "a1;b1;c1\na2;b2;c2\na3;b3;c3"
fobj = StringIO.StringIO(data)
```

To turn you string into a list, simply do: `data.splitlines()`.

---

Second, your csv file is `;` delimited so parsing it is not going to work unless you tell the `csv` module to expect it:

```
csv.register_dialect('semi', delimiter=';')
```

Then, you can do your thing:

```
json.dumps(list(csv.DictReader(fobj, fieldnames, dialect='semi')))
```

You'll get:

```
[
    {
        "col2": "b1", 
        "col3": "c1", 
        "col1": "a1"
    }, 
    {
        "col2": "b2", 
        "col3": "c2", 
        "col1": "a2"
    }, 
    {
        "col2": "b3", 
        "col3": "c3", 
        "col1": "a3"
    }
]
```

---

Note, you **cannot** read multiple times from a `StringIO` object, so if you try and pass it multiple times to your `csv.DictReader`, you won't get what you expect. You can "rewind" the `StringIO` object using: `fobj.seek(0)`.

Comment: `csv.DictReader()` operates on *iterables*; you can pass in a list if you really want to. `data.splitlines()` would do just fine, for example.

Comment: Next, you don't have to register a dialect either. `csv.reader()` and `csv.DictReader()` accept the `delimiter` argument as well. `csv.DictReader(data.splitlines(), fieldnames, delimiter=';')` is a lot more convenient for one-offs.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's a good observation, indeed. Updating to note that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have many things to learn with Python, hopefully, there are good teachers there ;)